# Populating TextBox based on ComBox, Insert into Database through TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, ado.net

I'm having troubles populating TextBoxes based on a ComboBox, Also insertion code won't work.

What should happen is, By selecting a customer from ComboBox, The details gets displayed on Text Boxes, And i can also add a customer to the ComboBox through the TextBoxes, Also there is a DataGridView displaying related info from another table based on my ComboBox selection but that's not the problem now.

Note:

I switched to Visual Studio 2012 recently, I'm assuming that's not a problem.

ComboBox exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll but was not handled in user code.

Save button exception:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

About the save button, The CustomerID is an Auto increment number, So i should be able to leave it's TextBox blank but it doesn't work when i do.

Table Structure:

```
Customers
    CustomerID [int] [PK] [AutoNumber]
    Name  [nvarchar]
    Phone1 [int]
    Phone2 [int]
    Address [nvarchar]
    Notes [ntext]
```

Code:

```
private void FillCombo()
{
    string code = "SELECT CustomerID, Name FROM Customers";
    SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(code, clsMain.con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    cBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    cBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cBox1.ValueMember = "CustomerID";
}

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clsMain.con.Open();
    FillCombo();
}

private void cBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string code = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID='" + cBox1.Text + "'";
    SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(code, clsMain.con);
    SqlCeCommandBuilder cmd = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(da);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    if (cBox1.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        txt1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CustomerID"].ToString();
        txt2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
        txt3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Phone1"].ToString();
        txt4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Phone2"].ToString();
        txt5.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Address"].ToString();
        txt6.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Notes"].ToString();
    }
}

private void stripSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string code = "INSERT INTO Customers VALUES (@CustomerID, @Name, @Phone1, @Phone2, @Address, @Notes)";
    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(code, clsMain.con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", (txt1.Text); //Tried Parse and Convert.
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txt2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone1", txt3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone2", txt4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txt5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", txt6.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Data stored.");
}
```

Sorry if it's a long code, But i thought it would be easier to spot the problems this way.

Comment: If CustomerID is an auto increment, why are you trying to save it to the database? Kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Yea you absolutely right, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `CustomerID` is integral value, So you need to change

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", txt1.Text);
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", Int32.Parse(txt1.Text));
```

---

as per `PhoenixReborn`

> if CustomerID is an auto increment, why are you trying to save it to the database? Kind of defeats the purpose.

then you need to edit your query to

```
string code = "INSERT INTO Customers(name, phone1, phone2, address, notes) VALUES (@Name, @Phone1, @Phone2, @Address, @Notes)";
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(code, clsMain.con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txt2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone1", txt3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone2", txt4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txt5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", txt6.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Data stored.");
```

Comment: I tried the last query it fixed the ID problem, but i'm still getting an exception on both Phone1 and Phone2, Even with .Parse and Convert.
Any ideas about populating the TextBoxes?
Thanks

Comment: i need to see your table structure!

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
    private void stripSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id;
        string code;
        SqlCeCommand cmd;

        /*
        If textbox is empty or input is not integer, then take the next id from table.
        Otherwise, id is set to input value.
        */
        if (txt1.Text == String.Empty || !int.TryParse(txt1.Text, out id))
        {
            /*
            Selects max id + 1
            If the table is empty, the result will be null
            and coalesce will return 0 for the first id number
            */
            code = "SELECT COALESCE((SELECT MAX(CustomerID) + 1 FROM Customers), 0);";
            cmd = new SqlCeCommand(code, clsMain.con);

            id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }

        code = "INSERT INTO Customers VALUES (@CustomerID, @Name, @Phone1, @Phone2, @Address, @Notes);";
        cmd = new SqlCeCommand(code, clsMain.con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txt2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone1", txt3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone2", txt4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txt5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", txt6.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Data stored.");
    }
```

By the way, an important note about your code: Prefer to connect to database everytime you execute a query and close it afterwards. What I mean is that instead of keeping connection open for all the execution time, use something like this:

```
    try
    {
        clsMain.con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        clsMain.con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (clsMain.con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            clsMain.con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: Weird this should work but i'm getting this exception;
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll.
No idea why!